# Split train / test data

Tags: python

I need to divide a data set into training and validation data sets. I tried to do 80-20, but it doesn't meet my expectations.

```
train_dataset, test_dataset = train_test_split(df, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

I have a city variable with 25 cities and several observations (at different dates) for each of them. What I want is that for each city and its observations, make an 80-20 division.
I don't know if this method has a name, but I don't know how to go about it.

Thank you.

Comment: You should always add which modules you use (if you use any) to provide context to people reading your question. Do you use the "sklearn" module? If so consider tagging the question as such to help relevant people find it and help you

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

def split_data(df: DataFrame, ratio: int): 
    length  = len(df)
    indices = list(range(length))
    np.random.shuffle(indices)

    train_indices = indices[:int(length * ratio)]
    test_indices  = indices[round(length * ratio):]

    train_set = df.iloc[train_indices]
    test_set  = df.iloc[test_indices]
    
    return (train_set, test_set)


train, test = split_data(df, 0.80)
```